# Travel distance of a rubber ball dropped and rebounding

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

> If a rubber ball is dropped from a height of $1\,\mathrm{m}$ and continues to rebound to a height that is nine tenth of its previous fall, find the total distance in meter that it travels on falls only.

#### My Attempt:

I tried if it could be solved using arithmetic progression for which the first term is $(a) = 1\,\mathrm{m}$ and the common difference is $(d) = \frac{9}{10}$. But I could not get any more information.

Comment: This is not arithmetic progression, where the next height is $\frac{8}{10}$. It is geometric progression where the next height is $\frac9{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10} = \frac{81}{100}$ (that's what "$\frac9{10}$ of its previous fall" is).

Comment: @Arthur, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There isn't much to elaborate on. The first fall is $1$. The second time it reaches a height which is $\frac9{10}$ of that, which is $\frac9{10}$. The third time, it reaches a height which is $\frac9{10}$ of the second time, which means $\frac9{10}\cdot\frac9{10}$. The fourth time it reaches a height which is $\frac9{10}$ of _that_ again, which means $\frac9{10}\cdot\frac9{10}\cdot\frac9{10}$. And so on. ("$\frac9{10}$ of" means "multiplied by $\frac9{10}$".) You want the sum of all of these, keeping in mind that the ball moves both up and down on its journey.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein As for elaboration you have that it rebounds $9/10$ of it's previous fall and what happens after that is that it will then fall that height too and the next rebound will be $9/10$ of that height...

Comment: yes because the ball will bounce negative distance next time

Answer (score 3):

The ball follows geometric progression, because, after each fall, the ball goes back up $\frac 9{10}$th of the height of the previous fall.

That is, if the ball fell down from $x$  metres, the next fall would be from $\frac 9{10} x$, the next from $\frac 9{10} \cdot \frac 9{10} x$.

Since the initial height is $1$ metre and we only have to evaluate the distance the ball falls, the excercise reduces to the sum of a simple Geometric progression, given by 
$$ 1+ \frac 9{10}  + \frac {9^2}{10^2}  + \frac {9^3}{10^3} + \cdots \infty$$

$$= \frac 1{1-\frac 9{10}}$$ 
 $$= 10$$
The total distance covered by the ball is $10$ metres.

Answer (score 0):

During the first drop it covers a distance of $1$m and then rises to a distance of $1\bullet\frac{9}{10}$ and then falls to that distance again to rise by $1\bullet\frac{9}{10}\bullet\frac{9}{10}$ and so on. You will notice that this is forming a geometric progression than a arithmetic one.

The summation of all the distances will be,

$1+1\bullet\frac{9}{10}+1\bullet(\frac{9}{10})^2+1\bullet(\frac{9}{10})^3...$

$=\frac{1}{1-\frac{9}{10}}=10$

Comment: Shouldn't you take the "falls" only?

Comment: @MattiP. fixed :p, didn't read it properly the first time. Thanks!

Comment: The answer should be 19m

Comment: @CYAries the question asks "find the total distance in meter that it travels on falls only"

Comment: @Devarshi I overlooked the question. Agree with your answer.